# Including layout in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

So created navigation drawer. It works like a charm, but I can't put my layout that I had before creating navigation drawer..

Here's the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<!-- This DrawerLayout has two children at the root  -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
    <!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I wonder, where do I put text for the layout that will appear in main activity?

Tried everywhere, constantly getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.`error